# Delphi soap requester - Problems accessing TLS1.1/TLS1.2

Tags: delphi, soap

I have asked this question of Embacadero Tech Support, raised a case there, but wondered also if anyone here knew an answer to this.

I work for a retail company and have written their Mail Order program in Delphi.

One thing the programme relies heavily on is processing credit card data. Since day one, this has never been much of an issue. Our gateway provider is Verifone in the UK and up until now I have used a SOAP requester to talk to the Verifone processing servers. I didn't have too many issues getting this working and it it has worked ever since. I don't profess to being an expert in SOAP calls etc though. This software, for component legacy reasons, resides still in D2007 and it is fine that way. I can still develop it as needed.

Until now......

Yesterday I received an e-mail from Verifone stating the following:

"On Tuesday 4th October 2016, Verifone will be making the following changes:
1. Upgrade security certificates from SHA-1 to the more secure, SHA-256 algorithm.
2. Retire support for SSL v3 and TLS v1.0."

They provided a link to this page:

http://www.verifone.co.uk/support/ssl

To begin with, I wasn't overly concerned, we have had some similar changes in the past (although mainly certificate changes) and this hasn't effected us. But the more I read it, the more I became a little concerned.

So I decided I had better run some tests. On that page on the second tab, there are some test URLs. I swapped our existing test URL (the test one we use for training on the system) with the new test one and...... it failed. I get the error:

"A connection with the server could not be established - URL:http://xml-cst.cxmlpg.com/gateway/gateway.asmx - SOAPAction:https://www.commidea.webservices.com/GetServerStatus"

Or similar to this screenshot which is an actual test credit card check rather than a server status check:

[image]

This was just doing a simple 'GetServerStatus' call which requires no account or credentials. I know the server is working using this URL in Chrome:

https://xml-cst.cxmlpg.com/gateway/gateway.asmx?op=GetServerStatus

I began to wonder if this was an issue in the components for the SOAP call in D2007.

So last evening I tried it at home in Seatlle. My thinking was that if I could at least getting it going there then I could write a little utility in Seattle that just sat alongside the D2007 Mail Order suite just to process the credit cards. I imported the WSDL from:

https://xml-cst.cxmlpg.com/gateway/gateway.asmx?wsdl

using the WSDL importer and added a button to a form to call the GetServerStatus function (in the same way that I got the original working in D2007):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
gs : GatewaySoap;

begin
gs := (HTTPRIO1 as GatewaySoap);
gs.GetServerStatus
end;
```

I kept my fingers crossed and clicked the button.

Alas, I got the same error message as above. So now I assume it is nothing to do with the Delphi version at all.

This is a very scary issue as basically it totally stops the automated functionality of the mail order software of which this is part. If I can't get the simple GetServerfStatus to work, then I am at a total loss.

Has anyone any ideas what is happening here? Is it that I can't do non-SSL/TLS1.0 via the SOAP requester? It looks like it has to be TLS1.1/1.2. How can i resolve this issue? I am guessing now that if it can resolved for Seattle then the same solution might apply to the existing Mail Order code in D2007.

Really hoping someone can help me out on this one! I was up verfy late last night trying different things, but can't get to grips with it. It could literally be somethhing I have just overlooked, something simple - which is my hope. Then again, I suspect it may be something a lot more technical.

Trevor

Comment: Indy supplied with D2007 probably didn't support [TLS1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4346) (published as RFC in April 2006) or [TLS1.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246) (published as RFC in August 2008). You'll have to update Indy for D2007. In Seattle, using Indy 10 and specifying `[sslvTLS1_1, sslvTLS1_2]` in `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and your thoughts on the problem. This isn't using Indy. It is using Delphi to import the WDSL from https://xml-cst.cxmlpg.com/gateway/gateway.asmx?wsdl and then use an THTTPPRIO component to make the calls. This works fine on the old URLS but no longer connects on the new URLS.

Comment: Delphi SOAP may use Indy (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24936972/6517492) instead of Wininet. If Chrome shows no error with the test Url, I guess it works because Chrome does not use Wininet.

Comment: OK, the SOAP stuff is using Wininet by default on Windows. If this is your case then disregard my comments about Indy. Anyway, if SOAP importer works so should SOAP calls from your app. You have to troubleshoot the connection error. What's the *exact* error message? What you posted seems to be incorrect (http instead of https).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I can see what you are saying, I guess Delphi needs to communicate somehow to when using SOAP. But will admit totally that I am no expert when it comes to web services and the like. I am fine on every day coding, but my knowledge of SOAP calls and INDY has been by example and converting Visual Basic examples. So I guess my question is how can I use the information you provided to my advantage to get this working? At home last night I have already tried this in Seattle which has Indy 10 installed by default. The problem was identical. Old URLS worked, new one didn't.

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the error message into the original post.

Comment: I've just made an experiment - created a new SOAP server with https support and imported its WSDL. The importer incorrectly generated the default URL as '**http**://localhost:8080/soap/IHelloService';. This caused the error `ESOAPHTTPException 'The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response - URL:http://localhost:8080/soap/IHelloService - SOAPAction:urn:HelloServiceIntf-IHelloService#echoDouble'`. Changing the `defURL` constant to '**https**://localhost:8080/soap/IHelloService' fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks again. Okay, I started from scratch, in Seatlle. Created a VCL project, imported the WSDL and changed the defURL. Dropped a THTTPRIO onto a form and set this up with correct WSDL and PORT and SERVICE. Added a button. Added code to call the GetServerStatus (as original post). But same error.

Comment: Try setting `URL` instead of `WSDL`, `Service` and `Port` on your RIO component.

Comment: Oh, that works! :) Certainly just on the simple server status call. Can I ask, why is that? Just so I understand the reasons why rather than just accepting it works. What I need to do now is, this evening, away from any live code, is to try and setup a program to send some test card data rather than just getiing the server status. I wonder even if the same solution will work in D2007? I will try that too. How do I mark your answer so you get the credit?

Comment: Being the curious person I am, I went back into the imported WSDL unit and removed the s from the defURL to make it simple HTTP again. And it still worked? I took the URL out of the component and set the WSDL again  with a service and port and it failed. Reverted back to just a URL and it works. I am just wondering why this is the case?

Comment: I've found that Delphi's SOAP web module wizard doesn't include the `poPublishLocationAsSecure` option in the `TWSDLHTMLPublish.PublishOptions` property which means the published WSDL returns **http** URLs for its services. If the client then relies on such WSDL you get this error because in fact all the URLs should be **https**. It seems like your SOAP server is written in Delphi and they forgot to include the option, too. So for your case, the fix on the server is to include `poPublishLocationAsSecure`, the work-around on the client is not to rely on WSDL, use a URL instead.

Comment: When you're using your own `THTTPRIO` you're not using the `Get***` function from the generated client unit so the `defURL` constant is irrelevant in that case.

Comment: They have caused me some pain, so I might politely point that out to them ;) Thanks for the clear explanation, always helps to understand a problem rather than just accept an answer. on the face of early tests, this might have fixed the issue. I will run some more comprehensive tests this evening with some test Credit Card data. Will up date tomorrow. I really appreciate your help with this and your patience whilst filling in the gaps in my knowledge - thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the SOAP server is returning http URLs for its services in the published WSDL (whereas they should be https).
If you control the SOAP server you should fix the WSDL generator. (If it's written in Delphi it's quite probably just missing `poPublishLocationAsSecure` option in their `TWSDLHTMLPublish.PublishOptions` property.
A possible workaround on the client might be to use a (https) URL directly and not rely on the published WSDL.

Comment: Hi, just a quick update. I tried this on the D2007 version last night and it fixed the problem with that too. So I don't need to do any large rewrites or seperate utilities. Embarcadero tech support came back with the same answer. I have reported the issue to Verifone but looks like it might take a bit of convincing as so far all the responses have been along the lines of "which bit do you mean" despite clearly stating exactly which wsdl and which part of it are incorrect! Anyway, just wanted to update, and to say thanks again for the help and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Another on of these "Features" of the FUBAR Delphi SOAP implementation: Query WSDL via HTTPS and get back HTTP URLs - sure, why not? Lets do a software upgrade, because we want to enable HTTPS URLs and nobody knew that we had to plan for a setting for this, because the library "designers" had a bad day and were not able to conclude this on the URLs being received!